# Git (bitbucket): Pull through ssh tunnel into existing repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Apparently, there are some troubles accessing bitbucket from Iran - where I am currently located. This concerns both the git workflows and their website. This is not censorship, as censorship replaces the page output with "real censorship". Here, I'm just getting timeouts and the following when I try to pull:

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have another computer in Europe that I can ping and ssh, so I thought pulling through that one. I am on Mac OS. I tried the following:

- Open one terminal window and

  ```
  ssh -L 3333:bitbucket.org:22 user@ssh-host -N
  ```
- Open another terminal window and go into `.git/config` and replace

  ```
  url = git@localhost:3333/project.git
  ```

However, I get

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As I am behind really terrible internet, it is important to not clone the project from scratch, but just update it using the repository that I already have locally.

For what it's worth - if it's a debugging command, here's the output from the commentator's command:

```
$ ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 104.192.143.2 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: `ssh -vvv bitbucket.org` or rather `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org`.

Comment: @Jakuje Sorry I'm not understanding what I'm supposed to do with that. Is that a debugging command, or should I put that into the .git/config?

Comment: The ssh tunnel just tunnels your localhost:3333 port to your ssh-host:22 port, not to bitbucket.org. Since you don't have a repository at your own server in Europe, you cannot clone from it. You may first mirror the bitbucket repo on your server and then clone it.

Comment: Can you use HTTPS? That might make it easier to communicate with bitbucket.

Comment: For a tunnel to work, you would need to map port 3333 of your intermediary server to bitbucket.org:22 (i.e. open the tunnel on your European server), and then you need to connect to that server on port 3333, not your localhost (localhost will always map to your own machine). So the URL should be something like `git@european-server:3333/project.git`.

Comment: @StanleyF. I actually do have the repository locally on that computer, too.

Comment: @poke I think HTTPS works, too. Regarding the tunnel suggestion - what would that mean, do I simply `ssh -L 3333:bitbucket.org:22`, or do I keep `user@ssh-host`? `ssh-host` is that European server, so I thought I was already implementing that.

Comment: Given your git config URL of `git@localhost:3333/project.git`, I was assuming that you did not set the remote URL to go to your `ssh-host` here. The config on your local machine should point to `git@ssh-host:3333/project.git` and your `ssh-host` should run the tunnel on port 3333

Comment: @poke The config is now pointing there, but what exactly do I run on my `ssh-host`? It appears non-sensical to me to do `ssh -L 3333:bitbucket.org:22 ssh-host -N` on the *remote* machine, but  `ssh -L 3333:bitbucket.org:22` will just trigger some information on usage of `ssh`.

Comment: Just `ssh -L 3333:bitbucket.org:22` on the `ssh-host` should work, but I’m not sure, I never created a tunnel like that before.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use vpn? I had exactly the same problem and using vpn helped me out..

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially go for something like adding the following to your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host bitbucket
HostName bitbucket.org
ProxyCommand ssh user@ssh-host nc %h %p
```

then just from your local host use this:

git@bitbucket/project.git

Comment: This leaves me with fatal: `'git@bitbucket/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`